# Google Maps Markers in wrong location, but lat/lon appears correct

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using custom markers to show a semi-live view of the location and orientation (heading) of certain vehicles of interest overlayed on Google Maps.  (In my case, I'm depicting aircraft, the same way Uber does for cars, or how FlightAware does for commercial flights).

The coordinates for the markers are being broadcast in JSON format to participating browsers from a server that I control.   The JSON data is processed by a JavaScript function at the browser to create / update the markers on the Google map.   The refresh (broadcast) rate can sometimes be as fast as once every 2-seconds, or as slow as once every 30 seconds, depending on the particular user's needs of the moment.

Sometimes, it is possible (and valid) for two markers to be thousands of miles apart from each other.  For example, one marker could be in Montana, and the other could be somewhere in Africa, and this is a valid condition.

However, sometimes, when I am zoomed into a region of the world so I can look more closely at one marker, a "ghost" marker appears nearby that "isn't really located there".  The ghost marker is labeled as one of the other markers that may be hundreds or thousands of miles away, but it's showing up in my zoomed in view for some strange reason.   If I momentarily zoom in our out, the ghost disappears, but it may re-appear again.

Interestingly, the ghost image has the proper orientation for the vehicle it represents, but it's just located in the wrong part of the world.

Are there any special things I should be doing when I'm updating multiple markers separated by large distances so they don't show up like this in the wrong place?

I have traced this as far as putting console messages in the browser so I can see the lat/lon of each marker being depicted.  I output the latLng object just before it's applied to each marker, and the lat/lon I see in the console log is correct, even when the actual marker shows up in the wrong place.

I don't know if this is a contributor to the problem, but the marker images I'm using are custom PNG files, not standard Google makers.   Has anybody run into this before?

Comment: A picture of this ghost marker might help identify what's going on

Comment: http://i1076.photobucket.com/albums/w442/GlassCoder2018/ghostairplane_zpsr2khoww5.jpg

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: That's easier said than done.   I'm not allowed to post a link to it in public, and I don't have a separate place to create a look-alike system (server and client) to demonstrate all this.   I'll have to wait to see if anybody has any ideas or suggestions based only on the text I've posted so far.   If that goes nowhere, then I will have to see what management will allow.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there are a couple of issues reported in the Google issue tracker very similar to the one you described here.

Have a look at them:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74225068

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73864685

Feel free to add your comments and star the issues to subscribe to further notifications from Google.

Please note that these issues were reported for the experimental version of Google Maps JavaScript API. Double check which version of the API you are using. Probably loading the release or frozen version will work as a temporary workaround for you.

For more details about versioning model of Google Maps JavaScript API please refer to the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

I hope this helps!